How to modify off-center circle in polar coordinates so that input angle has a linear relationship with angle on circle?
I have a circle translated horizontally in polar coordinates described by the equation:
$$r\left(\theta\right)=d\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{r_{0}^{2}-d^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)}$$
where $d$ is the horizontal displacement of the center of the circle from the origin, and $r_{0}$ as the radius of the circle.
In the specific case I have been looking at, $r_{0}>d$ and $d<0$, if that makes any difference.
How would I find a function $f\left(\theta\right)$ so that when I input an angle $\theta$, the expression $r\left(f\left(\theta\right)\right)$ returns the position on the circle such that the angle this point makes with the horizontal around the center of the circle is equal to my input angle $\theta$? Currently the function does not have this property, an input angle in relation to the origin is not necessarily the angle of the point with the translated center of the circle.
In other words, if I graph the function from $r\left(f\left(0\right)\right)$ to $r\left(f\left(\theta\right)\right)$, I want the circle to go $\theta$ radians around, ie $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ will draw the first fourth of the translated circle from the horizontal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. As the function $r\left(\theta\right)$ currently stands, this is true for $t=0$, $t=\frac{1}{2}$, and $t=1$ only. So then I think I want $f\left(\theta\right)$ to be some sort of mapping that has fixed points $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$, and $1$.
I can guess that this function might have to do something with $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=−d\sin(θ)−\frac{d^{2}\cos(θ)\sin(θ)}{\sqrt{r^{2}_{0}−d^{2}\sin^{2}(θ)}}$, but I am not sure exactly what to do with the derivative or if this is the correct path to take.

You need to express the polar angle $\theta$ as a function of central angle $\phi$ (see figure below). From the sine rule applied to triangle $OCP$ we get:
$$
{r_0\over\sin\theta}={d\over\sin(\phi-\theta)},
$$
which can be solved for $\theta$ giving:
$$
\tan\theta={r_0\sin\phi\over d+r_0\cos\phi}.
$$

